# how can I config the ar drone to detect tags using node.js?

Tags: node.js, ar.drone

I am using parrot ar drone 2.0 and trying see if it detects the oriented roundel. This is a part of my code:

```
client.config('CAD_TYPE_ORIENTED_ROUNDEL_BW', 12);
client.config('general:navdata_demo', 'FALSE');
```

and later i have:

```
console.log('cameraSource:' + d.visionDetect.cameraSource);

console.log('tag_count:' + d.visionDetect.nbDetected);
console.log('tag_type:' + d.visionDetect.type);
```

But the number of tags and everything remains zero despite the drone moving above the tag. 
I am a bit new to node.js so can somebody please tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to type all configurations in lower case letters. 
so with this configuration it can detect it.

```
client.config('detect:detect_type', 12);
```

number 12 corresponds to the black and white oriented roundel.